# Specifying Random Tuple Visitation Order in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, relational-database

In principle, some queries could be sped up by visiting the rows in random order, rather than the order on disk (which is presumably related to order of insertion, although `VACUUM` operations and such can reclaim and re-order space). An example of this would be a distinct(key) query with sequential keys having high cardinality values. For example, suppose a relation `X(k TEXT, v INT)` has the following data arranged in left-to-right order on disk:

> (a,0),(a,1),(a,2)...(a,10^N),(b,10),(b,0),(b,1),(b,2)...(b,10^N),(d,0),(d,1),(d,2)...(d,10^N),(h,0),(h,1),(h,2)...(h,10^N).

If we wanted to stream the output of

```
SELECT distinct(k) FROM X
```

we could in principle get answers much more quickly if the order of visiting tuples was random (of course, to get the full answer, we will need to visit all the tuples anyway, but I'm considering a streaming setting or even a setting where getting 99% of the data is a suitable approximation).

One possible objection to the idea of random tuple visitation is that today's hardware makes block-wise I/O and buffering orders of magnitude faster than individual random access, but that does not really affect the main idea because we could imagine visiting random *blocks* rather than random *tuples* (keeping track of what blocks have been visited so far to avoid duplicate reads).

It looks like postgres and sqlite do not support this idea, or at least it is not exposed in the SQL with something like

```
SELECT distinct(k) FROM X [VISITING {random_tuples,sequential_blocks_from_beginning, sequential_blocks_from_end,random blocks}]
```

Is there some way to do what I'm looking to do? If not, is there a reason other than happenstance of what has been implemented in software so far?

Comment: You might get the distinct list of values faster (if the DBMS returns a value as soon as it's found), but overall resource usage and runtime would probablyincrease. And if you don't want to read 100% of the rows you can request a random sample and then do the distinct on top of that (but this will be an approximate result).

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. `distinct(k)` is the same as `distinct k`

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. The query optimizer will do a sequential scan on the table if it thinks that's cheaper then random I/O - and the seq scan **will** be block-wise I/O (at least Postgres will, I don't use SQLite). The execution plan will tell you